# Get current IServiceScope in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

How one could get an instance of the current (per-request) `IServiceScope` in a controller? In a service?

The plan is to use it to resolve services that belongs to the same scope.

Comment: ctor(IServiceProvider scope) instead

Answer (score 8):

> *get an instance ... in a controller*:

1. There're no need to use `IHttpContextAccessor` within a **Controller**. There's already a **[`HttpContext` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_HttpContext)** for you. If you want to access `HttpContext`, just

   ```cs
   // no need to use IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext
   var svc = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();
   ```
2. Or as an alternative, inject the `IServiceProvider` directly:

   ```cs
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
       private IServiceProvider _sp;
       public MyController(IServiceProvider sp)
       {
           this._sp = sp;
       }
   }
   ```

   and when you want a small scope, you can create it as below:

   ```
   public IActionResult MyActoin()
   {
       // create a more small scope
       using (var scope = this._sp.CreateScope())
       {
           var sp = scope.ServiceProvider;
           // now you get the services from this small scope
           var svc1 = sp.GetRequiredService<MyService1>();
           var svc2 = sp.GetRequiredService<MyService2>();
           //...
       }
       return new JsonResult("it works");
   }
   ```
3. In particular, if the required service's scope is exactly the Request Scope, just inject them all:

   ```
   public class MyController : Controller
   {
       private IServiceProvider _sp;
       private readonly MyService1 _service1;
       private readonly MyService2 _service2;

       public MyController(IServiceProvider sp, MyService1 service1, MyService2 service2,...)
       {
           this._sp = sp;
           this._service1 = service1;
           this._service2 = service2;
       }
   ```

Comment: why do you need to `create a more small scope` ?.. why not `sp.GetRequiredService` directly ?

Comment: You are correct with your answer. My bad oversimplifying the question: originally I intended to mention a deeper dependency tree: a service that is resolved for another service in a controller. So, controller here is mentioned cause I was aware of Asp.NET controllers aren't registered in (root) service provider by default.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to ask for `IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor` in controller's constructor and then resolve the desired services from it:

`var svc = contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<MyService>();`

Comment: is there more elegant way? I'd like to decouple myself from `IHttpContextAccessor`